# Проверить наличие символов, отличных от "0-9 a-zA-Z"?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как проверить существуют ли в строке какие-либо символы отличные от цифр, латинских букв и пробелов?

На ум приходит убирать все лишнее и после сравнивать с исходным вариантом. Может существует другой способ?

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9 a-zA-Z]/', '', 'example text');
```

Comment: Зачем заменять, если можно найти первое вхождение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функцию preg_match, она возвращает 1 если строка соответствующая регулярному выражению найдена, и 0, если нет

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

Выражение, например, может быть таким: `/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]+/`, а ф-я `preg_match`. Тест можно посмотреть [здесь](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/wnC).

Если будет возвращен массив ненулевой длины, то, наличие нежелательных символов определилось.